# Calling a boolean function inside a 2nd function? - Python

Tags: python, function, boolean

I currently have a working function here:

```
def median(alist):
   copylist = alist[:]
   copylist.sort()

   if len(copylist)%2 == 0:
       rightmid = len(copylist)//2
       leftmid = rightmid - 1
       median = (copylist[leftmid] + copylist[rightmid])//2
   else:
       mid = len(copylist)//2
       median = copylist[mid]
   return median
```

and I would like this function to call a second function isEven in the first function. Here is the second function:

```
def isEven(n):
   if n % 2 == 0:
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

Is this the correct way to do it or is there another to shorten the code in the median function?

```
def median(alist):
   copylist = alist[:]
   copylist.sort()

   if isEven(len(alist)) == True:
       rightmid = len(copylist)//2
       leftmid = rightmid - 1
       median = (copylist[leftmid] + copylist[rightmid])//2
   else:
       mid = len(copylist)//2
       median = copylist[mid]
   return median
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this should shorten the amount of your code in median quite a bit, even without requiring the auxiliary method `isEven`:

```
def median(alist):
  copylist  = sorted(alist)
  index = (len(alist) - 1) // 2
  if len(alist) % 2:
    return copylist[index]
  else:
    return (copylist[index] + copylist[index + 1]) / 2.0

# Testing
print(median([3,1,2])) #2
print(median([4,2,3,1])) #2.5
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FrCl/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered, but I'd add the following readability enhancement, if you're interested:

I would change your `isEven` function to have the following signature:

```
def hasEvenNumberOfMembers(list):
    if len(list) % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And then change the `if` statement in `median` to read:

`if hasEvenNumberOfMembers(alist):`

which I think makes things a lot more readable.  Just my 2c.